# Extract combination of items from database based on column values

Tags: algorithm

I have a database of food items (approx. 2000 items) and their nutritional values (nutrition per 100 grams). I want to create a function that extracts one optimal or multiple combinations of food items that are as close to a certain defined combination of nutritional values as possible.

It's kind of like an extreme version of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). What I'm doing currently is sorting the items by each nutritional value, and manually combing through them to find combinations that work somewhat. But figuring out a way to do this programmatically would be gold.

Not sure if I'm in the right forum or if the question is specific enough. And I'm certainly not expecting code snippets or full solutions. Just trying to figure out if it's even possible to accomplish.

Comment: As you already figured out it's a knapsack problem. You can find plenty of code that solves it on the www. For 2000 items it should be feasible to solve it.

Comment: Don't forget it's 2000 items AND about 30 different types of values for each item, not just size/value. And it's all in amounts per 100g, which means I have to figure out how much of each item I can fit into the "knapsack".

Comment: Your question indicates that you are only interested in the 'nutritional values' as constraint for your solution.

Comment: Yes, but there are 30 ish different nutritional values to take into account.

Comment: I still think you can handel it brute force. At least if you restrict the maximal number of different foot items allowed in a result.